# How to make fields mandatory?

Tags: validation, jsf

I am working on an user registration form. I want to make certain fields mandatory. What JSF tags can I use to make the fields mandatory?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `required="true"` attribute in `<h:inputText>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<p:inputText required="true"`, its easy and fast.

**OR Use Bean Validation.**

Bean Validation is a standard validation specification that allows us to easily validate domain objects by using a set of constraints declared in the form of annotations.

New built-in constraints: `@Email, @NotEmpty, @NotBlank, @Positive, @PositiveOrZero, @Negative, @NegativeOrZero, @PastOrPresent and @FutureOrPresent`